# Get DataExtension absolute url

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

After creating a DataExtension using SOAP API, I am able to get the details like CustomerKey/ObjectID of the data extension. I would like to get the absolute url(deep link) of the data extension, so that the url can be used to redirect to the DE from external applications.

Is it possible to build the url given CustomerKey/ObjectID?

Answer (score 0):

So from Contact Builder > Data extensions I right clicked on a link and got this url:

(replace ##CUSTOMOBJECTID## with your GUID) (and you stack SXX or S7/s10)

https://mc.sXX.exacttarget.com/contactsmeta/admin.html#admin/data-extension/##CUSTOMOBJECTID##/properties/